# Wordpress Author URLs redirected to Home Page

Tags: php, wordpress, seo

I have tried to set up an author page in wordpress. But all the author pages are redirected to the home page. I google it and they suggested to disable plugins and then check the author pages. I tried it and found that [Yoast wordpress SEO plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wordpress-seo/) causes this problem. But i really want to use this plugin for SEO. Please help how to handle this. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If Yoast's plugin seems to be causing the problem — don't bother touching the code.

Instead, just install any of the other SEO plugins. They're just as good.

Answer (score 14):

Go into SEO/Titles & Metas then click 'Other' in the top tabs.

Untick 'Disable the author archives' and your problem will be solved.

Comment: It sucks that it does that.  I had spent 2 days on this with no idea why the redirects were happening.  Glad it is resolved.  Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

To resolve it Do This in admin section. plugin Version 7.0.1

SEO -> Search Appearance  -> Archives -> Author archives settings -> Author archives -> marked it as Enabled.

Answer (score 3):

I found out how Yoast SEO plugin determines whether to set the redirect or not. 
The redirect is set if you have answered in the configuration manager of Yoast SEO that the site does not have multiple authors (SEO-> Dashboard-> General -> Configuration wizard). The reason for that is to avoid duplicated from SEO perspective content, because your author and your blog page will have the same content, if the site has only one author.

Comment: This is indeed the actual issue that will resolve it. I suggest not to touch the code like the option above. On-update you'll need to do it again, and you probably will have forgotten it by then.

Answer (score 1):

You need to edit the class `frontend` in folder `frontend` and delete this line

```
( isset( $options['disable-author'] ) && $options['disable-author'] && $wp_query->is_author ) ||
```

Then the author pages will not redirect.